# Dejar de mostrar opciones en selects que estan seleccionadas en otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

La situación es la siguiente:

Tengo 2 selects que tienen las mismas opciones. Lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione 1 o más opciones en uno de ellos en el otro no salgan a elegir esas opciones y viceversa,cada vez que seleccione una opción en uno no puede aparecer en el otro.A continuación muestro el código como lo tengo que solo me funciona bien en una sola dirección. Gracias de antemano.

```js
  $('.muestra,.oculta').select2();

  $('.muestra').change(function(){

    $('.oculta').html(''); //Clear
    $('.muestra option:not(:selected)')
        .clone()
        .appendTo('.oculta')
});

$('.oculta').change(function(){
    $('.muestra').html(''); //Clear
    $('.oculta option:not(:selected)')
        .clone()
        .appendTo('.muestra')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.js"></script>

<div>
 <select class="muestra form-control"multiple name="state"style="width:20%">
   <option value="a">seleccione</option>
   <option value="opcion1"disabled>opcion1</option>
   <option value="opcion2">opcion2</option>
 </select>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
 <select class="oculta form-control"multiple name="state"style="width:20%">
  <option value="a">seleccione</option>
   <option value="opcion1">opcion1</option>
   <option value="opcion2">opcion2</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo logré hacer de la siguiente deshabilitando los options que no estaban seleccionados y ocultandolos con css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] { display: none;}
</style>

    $( document ).on('ready',function() {

$('.muestra').select2();
$('.oculta').select2();




$('.muestra').change(function(){

var x = $('.muestra').val();

$('.oculta option').each(function(i){

    var y = $(this).val()

    if($.inArray(y, x) == -1){
        $('.oculta option[value ='+ y +']').prop('disabled', false);

    }else{

        $('.oculta option[value ='+ y +']').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

    }


});




});



$('.oculta').change(function(){

var x = $('.oculta').val();

$('.muestra option').each(function(i){

    var y = $(this).val()

    if($.inArray(y, x) == -1){
        $('.muestra option[value ='+ y +']').prop('disabled', false);
        //$('.oculta option[value ='+ y +']').css('display','');
    }else{

        $('.muestra option[value ='+ y +']').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        //$('.oculta option[value ='+ y +']').css('display','none');
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que definir quizá mas exactamente el comportamiento que esperas porque al afectarse mutuamente y poder eliminarse las opciones, con un par de clicks no quedarían opciones, te dejo un ejemplo de como podría hacerse, pero usando `disabled` para que se vea la mecánica, además a los no seleccionados le quito el `disabled` para que no quede bloqueado todo.

Sea como sea, lo que se puede hacer es  hacer un `forEach` de los `options` del otro `select` y  ver cual `value` es igual a los del array de values del `select` con `includes()`, en los casos en que los values con iguales, se hace algo:

```js
  $('.muestra').change(function() {
    const opciones = $(this).val();

    [...$('.oculta option')].forEach(o => {

      o.disabled = (opciones.includes(o.value)) ? true : false;

    });

  });

  $('.oculta').change(function() {
    const opciones = $(this).val();

    [...$('.muestra option')].forEach(o => {

      o.disabled = (opciones.includes(o.value)) ? true : false;

    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.js"></script>

<div>
  <select class="muestra form-control" multiple name="state" style="width:20%">
    <option value="a">seleccione</option>
    <option value="opcion1">opcion1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">opcion2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <select class="oculta form-control" multiple name="state" style="width:20%">
    <option value="a">seleccione</option>
    <option value="opcion1">opcion1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">opcion2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```